# HyperJAXB3 - Parsing XSD including xs:any wildcards

Tags: xml, jpa, xsd, jaxb, hyperjaxb

I have a huge xsd schema (the open source railML 2.2 format) for which I am trying to create a JPA annotated object model. I want to use HyperJAXB3 for that.

The XSD schema includes some `<xs:any namespace="##other" />` elements. I have no chance to change the xsd files. The hyperjaxb compiler gives the error:

```
Class [org.railml.schemas._2013.TElementWithIDAndName] declares an attribute wildcard. This is currently not supported. See issue #46.
```

So Hyperjaxb seems to have problems with these wildcard constructions. I tried to add a `hj:ignored` binding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:hj="http://hyperjaxb3.jvnet.org/ejb/schemas/customizations"
    version="2.1">
    <!-- global bindings -->
    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:simple />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>

    <jaxb:bindings
        schemaLocation="genericRailML.xsd">

        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:schema//xs:complexType[@name='tElementWithIDAndName']//xs:sequence//xs:any">
            <hj:ignored/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>    
</jaxb:bindings>
```

But then the compiler gives:

```
[ERROR] compiler was unable to honor ignored customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
```

The referenced XSD part:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:rail="http://www.railml.org/schemas/2013" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" targetNamespace="http://www.railml.org/schemas/2013" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="2.2">

...

  <xs:complexType name="tElementWithIDAndName">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>generic base type, used for inheritance of many railML types</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="additionalName" type="rail:tAdditionalName" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:annotation>
          ...
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="strict" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>provide an extension point for non-railML elements in foreign namespace</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:any>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="rail:tGenericID" use="required">
      ...
    </xs:attribute>
    ...
  </xs:complexType>

...
</xs:schema>
```

Is there a way to parse the XSD document with HyperJAXB or is there a way to bypass the `xs:any` elements?

Comment: First, you should be aware that I no longer actively develop Hyperjaxb.

Comment: Please send me a PR with minimal reproducing project here:
https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3-support under `r/railml`.

Comment: Do you want to ignore these `xs:any` items altogether? Or only wildcard attributes?

Comment: Thanks for the possibility. Finally I need the whole railML schema to be imported as it is. I am not sure whether HyperJaxb can deal with xs:any or the wildcards. I thought that the xs:any is the problem, isn't it?

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't use HJ for a schema like railML. Do you really need tabular storage? Won't document storage in NoSQL-Style be better?

Comment: In principle yes, HJ3 can deal with wildcards but they'll be stored as serialized DOM elements as far as I rememeber. In any case it won't be really "rational style".

Comment: I will check the NoSQL idea. But In that special case: Yes I need a tabular style.